# Expect scripts need a focused window session to work?

Tags: rsync, expect

I have the following expect script to sync a local folder with a remote one:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    # Expect script to interact with password based commands. It synchronize a local 
    # folder with an remote in both directions.
    # This script needs 5 argument to work:
    # password = Password of remote UNIX server, for root user.
    # user_ip = user@server format
    # dir1=directory in remote server with / final
    # dir2=local directory with / final
    # target=target directory
    # set Variables
    set password [lrange $argv 0 0] 
    set user_ip [lrange $argv 1 1]   
    set dir1 [lrange $argv 2 2]   
    set dir2 [lrange $argv 3 3]   
    set target [lrange $argv 4 4]   
    set timeout 10   
    # now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
    spawn rsync -ruvzt -e ssh $user_ip:$dir1$target $dir2
    match_max 100000
    expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
    send "yes\n"
    exp_continue
    }
    # Look for password prompt
    "*?assword*" {
    # Send password aka $password 
    send -- "$password\r"
    # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
    send -- "\r"
    interact
    }
    }
    spawn rsync -ruvzt -e ssh $dir2$target $user_ip:$dir1
    match_max 100000
    expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
    send "yes\n"
    exp_continue
    }
    # Look for password prompt
    "*?assword*" {
    # Send password aka $password 
    send -- "$password\r"
    # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
    send -- "\r"
    interact
    }
    }
    spawn ssh $user_ip /home/pi/bash/cerca_del.sh $dir1$target
    match_max 100000
    expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
    send "yes\n"
    exp_continue
    }
    # Look for passwod prompt
    "*?assword*" {
    # Send password aka $password 
    send -- "$password\r"
    # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
    send -- "\r"
    interact
    }
    }
```

It work properly if I execute it in a gnome_terminal window, but it stops to the password request if I execute in foreground (such us using ALT+F2 combination, or with crone, or with a startup script).

I don't found information if expect needs of an active windows terminal to interact correctly.

Somebody else experiments this strange behaviour? It is a feature or a bug? Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an error message? Try adding `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script and run it in cron. In my experience, when things don't work in cron, it's due to a difference in your environment and cron's environment (i.e. $PATH is different). However, rsync should be located in /usr/bin or /bin.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. There are no error messages. The script only stops to the first interaction. Cron continue to don't work (any of the availlable output-type work). When I run the script in a non terminal window appear to me (and rapidly disappear) many dialog-windows. I think one for each interaction. I'd like to focus the discussion in differences between running the script in a terminal window or without. I think this is the point of the problem.

Comment: The question can be: is it known that _expect_ needs a terminal windows to parse command output and to interact with them?

Comment: No, expect does not require a graphical environment: it is perfectly happy to run in cron or in a console or any non-GUI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented to Glenn's answer, I saw that the problem wasn't the terminal windows but the way the script is called.
My expect script is called several times by another BASH script with the rude line: "/path/expect-script-name.exp [parameters]". Opening a terminal window (in any desktop environment), I can execute the caller script by: "/path/bash-script-name.sh". In this way, everything run well because the shebang is used to call the right shell (in this case EXPECT). 
I added in the start-up system list the BASH script (i.e. the caller script of the EXPECT script) working in a non-focused terminal window instance. This last way gives errors.

The solution is calling explicitly the EXPECT script in the BASH script in the way: "expect /path/expect-script-name.exp".

I found that without this explicit call the shell DASH manages all the scripts (included the EXPECT scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several errors. A quick re-write:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Expect script to interact with password based commands. It synchronize a local 
# folder with an remote in both directions.
# This script needs 5 argument to work:
# password = Password of remote UNIX server, for root user.
# user_ip = user@server format
# dir1=directory in remote server with / final
# dir2=local directory with / final
# target=target directory
# set Variables

lassign $argv password user_ip dir1 dir2 target
set timeout 10   

spawn /bin/sh
set sh_prompt {\$ $}
expect -re $sh_prompt
match_max 100000

# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
send rsync -ruvzt -e ssh $user_ip:$dir1$target $dir2
expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*?assword*" {
        # Look for password prompt
        # Send password aka $password 
        send -- "$password\r"
        # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
        send -- "\r"
    }
    -re $sh_prompt
}

send rsync -ruvzt -e ssh $dir2$target $user_ip:$dir1
expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*?assword*" {
        send -- "$password\r"
        send -- "\r"
    }
    -re $sh_prompt
}

send ssh $user_ip /home/pi/bash/cerca_del.sh $dir1$target
expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*?assword*" {
        send -- "$password\r"
        send -- "\r"
    }
    -re $sh_prompt
}
```

Main points:

- you were spawning several commands instead of spawning a shell and sending the commands to it
- you put a comment outside of an action block (more details below)
- the interact command gives control back to the user, which you don't want in a cron script

Why a comment in a multi-pattern expect block is bad:

Tcl doesn't treat commands like other languages do: the comment character only acts like a comment when it appears in a place that a command can go. That's why you see end-of-line comments in expect/tcl code like this

```
command arg arg ...     ;# this is the comment
```

If that semi-colon was missing, the `#` would be handles as just another argument for the command.

A mult-pattern expect command  looks like

```
expect pattern1 {body1} pattern2 {body2} ...
```

or with line continuations

```
expect \
    pattern1 {body1} \
    pattern2 {body2} \
    ...
```

Or in braces (best style, and as you've written)

```
expect {
    pattern1 {body1} 
    pattern2 {body2} 
    ...
}
```

The pattern may be optionally preceded with -exact, -regexp, -glob and --

When you put a comment in there where like this:

```
expect {
    pattern1 {body1} 
    # this is a comment
    pattern2 {body2} 
    ...
}
```

Expect is not looking for a new command there: it will interpret the block like this

```
expect {
    pattern1 {body1} 
    #        this
    is       a
    comment  pattern2
    {body2}  ...
}
```

When you put the comment inside an action body, as I've done above, then you're safe because the body is evaluated according to the rules of Tcl (spelled out in the 12 whole rules [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)).

Phew. Hope that helps. I highly recommend that you check out [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do) for all the details.

Comment: First of all sorry for my late.
Thank you Glenn, yours advices are really useful but they do not hit the problem. 
I want to state here for those that will found a similar problem: I was calling the expect script by a another shell script in the Ubuntu start-up sequence; it seems that Ubuntu to accellerate the boot-up sequence is using DASH. This peculiar shell do not manage the shebang #!/usr/bin/expect -f and uses itself as unique shell.

Comment: The shell does not manage the shebang at all, the OS does (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/execve.2.html). This startup sequence you refer to must specifically invoke the script with `source` or `sh`. If your problem is solved, please provide an answer -- that will be most helpful for future readers.